# Independent binomial random variables with multiple parameters?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent binomial random variables with parameters $n_1=3$ and $n_2=4$, and $p=0.3$(same for both), and $Z=X+Y$, what is $E(X^2 Y)$?

I know that $E(Z)=(n_1 + n_2)p$ but I'm confused as to how you use the given parameters to calculate $E(X^2 Y)$.

If I'm not mistaken, $E(X^2 Y)=E(X^2)E(Y)$ so that simplifies things but I don't really know where to go from there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you find $E[X^2]?$

Comment: Let's say I was going to calculate just $E(X)$, I'd need to find $np$ but the initial equation $Z=X+Y$ is throwing me off because I know how to find the expected value of Z but not X and Y

Comment: If you know the expected value of a binomial is $np,$ then what is preventing you from finding $E[X]$ and $E[Y]?$

Comment: Note that $\text{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$. And you probably know the mean and variance.

Comment: Would you just use $n1$ for calculating $X$ and $n2$ for calculating $Y$? So $E(X)=(3*0.3)$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $\mathbb E[X^2Y]=\mathbb E[X^2]\mathbb E[Y]$. Then $$\mathbb E[X^2] = \mathbb E[X]^2 + \mathrm{Var}(X) = n_1^2p^2 + n_1p(1-p)$$ and $\mathbb E[Y] = n_2p$. So $$\mathbb E[X^2Y]= (n_1^2p^2 + n_1p(1-p))n_2p.$$